# How to get index of word or syllable in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

i need to get location(index) of word or syllable of NSString. I'm sorry about i can't post any code because i have no idea where to start. I m working with web service and service will be back to me word or syllable in sentence and will tell me any color and i have to change color of word in sentence. I figured this out how to change color of character but i need to know index of it.  I will be really thankful for any clue or help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you bothered to look at the specs for NSString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate words with index:

```
NSString *s = @"How to get index of word or syllable in NSString";
__block NSUInteger i = 0;
[s enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])
                      options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                   usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                       NSLog(@"%lu %@", i++, substring);
                   }];
```

That will print

```
0 How
1 to
2 get
```

etc.

An equivalent way would be:

```
NSUInteger words = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: s];
NSString *capture;
NSCharacterSet *whiteSpace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
while ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:whiteSpace intoString:&capture]){
    NSLog(@"%lu %@", words++, capture);
}
```

but relies on spaces, tabs, and newlines as separators. The first way is better.

Comment: Thank you, this working perfectly but this is not what i exactly want, for example i need to get start and end indexs of "index" word in "How to get index of word or syllable in NSString"  this is possible?

Comment: NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"index" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]; 
NSLog(@"start = %lu, end = %lu",range.location, range.location + [@"index" length]);

Answer (score 3):

To get the words in a string, you can call:

```
    NSString *string = @"How to get index";
    NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"%lu",[words indexOfObject: @"get"]); // outputs 2 (starts at 0)
```

Separating by syllable is language-dependant and much, much harder to do.